# Tuleap - Tracker - Export - columns broken

Tags: tuleap

End of line character break the columns when exporting tracker to Excel.
Example : 
in a tracker from requirement model, if description has more than one line, the export will not show the proper columns

Comment: What is the language/CSV separator preferences of your Tuleap account and what is the language Excel ?

Comment: CSV separator is set to COMMA. Excel language is english

Answer (score 0):

I just did a couple of tests with Tuleap in en_US, OpenOffice in english (on a Linux base) and comma as separator and everything works just fine.

I would suggest to check at excel side if there is a configuration option to manage end of line. As windows and unix have a different handling of this it might be the source of the problem